# Show page only when its been redirected but not typing in url using php

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I am trying to show a page only when its redirected through submit button.For example.
If the main url is `http://www.example.com`

```
 Am having form in `http://wwww.example.com/form.php` and when its submitted its         
 redirected to http://wwww.example.com/success.php
```

but if the user types `http://wwww.example.com/success.php` in the browser URL how can I redirect it to `form.php` if the form is not submitted.

Comment: check if $_POST[] is empty then redirect to forms.php

Comment: Set a session value on `form.php` on `success.php` load delete it. If the session value isn't on `success.php` redirect to the home page or where ever you want a manual load to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a SESSION variable on form.php just before redirecting to success.php & check that SESSION variable on success.php. Just like this:

On form.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$SESSION['user'] = '$user_name';    //Put your username in this or any value which you want to check on success.php page
header("Location : http://wwww.example.com/success.php");
?>
```

And now on success.php

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($SESSION['user'])){
   header("Location : http://wwww.example.com/form.php");
}

//Now your success.php code & content
?>
```

Hope, this may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

On success.php

```
<?php if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {header('Location: http://wwww.example.com/form.php');die();}?>
```